# Adding Sub category under category in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a scenario where I have a dropdowns for category and sub category. I want to add the sub categoy under the respective sub category from the front end. I have done the coede for category section. Please help me with to add the sub-category under the respective category.

Please see the code  so far which I did:-

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCategoryAdding" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" Text="Add Category" Width="100" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
</div>
```

Button click code for adding the category:-

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
    {
        string query;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        query = "Insert into Categories_For_Merchant values ('" + txtCategoryAdding.Text + "', '" + txtDescription.Text + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Category added succesfully');</script>");
        txtCategoryAdding.Text = "";
        txtDescription.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be something the same, just have the parentId saved somewhere to use it while adding the sub one

Comment: @AmrElGarhy: I have the CategoryId as ParentID in my table.Just need some quick step to start with. Can you Please suggest

Comment: how do you want it to work, do you have ideas about the work flow or the UI? do you want everything on the same page or on different steps?

Comment: I want whenever I add category, there should also be option to add subcategory for the respective category. Yes I want everything in same page. Will this be logically fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a panel inside the div and make it hidden, and on your insert category button click you can show it.
This panel should contain the sub category controls to submit.

Answer (score 0):

create a field in your database able as parent_id and remember categoryId and parentId are different fields
so your table look like this
       categoryId    categoryName   parentId and others.

just put a dropdownlist for parentCategory before first textbox .

```
  <div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_parent" runat="server" Width="160px" ></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCategoryAdding" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" Text="Add Category" Width="100" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click"
    />
 </div>


   on page_load event on .cs page

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

       SqlConnection conn = new  SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();  
        SqlDataAdapter ad1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        ad1.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select categoryID,categoryName from  
                   Categories_For_Merchant where parent_id=0",conn);
        ds = new DataSet();
        ad1.Fill(ds,"parent_cat");


        ddl_parent.DataSource = ds.Tables["parent_cat"];
        ddl_parent.DataTextField = "categoryID";
        ddl_parent.DataValueField = "categoryName ";
        ddl_parent.DataBind();
        ddl_parent.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));
        conn.close();
```

}

after submit button

```
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
   {
    string query;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    query = "Insert into Categories_For_Merchant values (ddl_category.selectedItem.value,'" + txtCategoryAdding.Text + "', '" + txtDescription.Text + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Category added succesfully');</script>");
    txtCategoryAdding.Text = "";
    txtDescription.Text = "";
}
```

}

Comment: hi, I already have the field for category and sub category. I just want to add the sub category.

Comment: So use subcategory as parentId and category as category

Comment: Ok, will try and let you know